# stored procedure - pass multiple values for IN clause

Tags: amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I'm writing a stored procedure for Postgres, just do `select * from table where id in (value1, value2, ...)`.

These values will be getting from the variable.

### My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE record_example(v_name varchar(100), v_id int)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  rec RECORD;
  BEGIN
  FOR rec IN select id, updated from mytable where names in (v_name) and id=v_id
  LOOP
     RAISE INFO 'id = % and updated = %', rec.id, rec.updated;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

This actually works if I use single value for `v_name`.

#### Ex:

```
call record_example('myname',101);
```

But if I do multiple values, its not working.

#### HELP 1 :

```
call record_example('myname, your_name',101);
```

It just returned CALL, that's it. Nothing happened.

#### HELP 2:

Sometimes the `v_id` variable is optional, so that time the FOR loop should inclue the `id=v_id`

Ex:

```
FOR rec IN select id, updated from mytable where names in (v_name) 
  LOOP
     RAISE INFO 'id = % and updated = %', rec.id, rec.updated;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: If you want to return something, write a function not a procedure.

Comment: Its just a sample code, my actual workload is to get results and start writing into other tables and more process. So I taught to learn this fundamental stuff with this small example.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots they are very different.

Comment: Oh ok, Its for Redshift. I thought both will have the same syntax. Altest if I can get something guidance  for Help1 would be great.